# How to match diagonal records in Oracle Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have table called test and it has 3 columns src, dest and distance in below format

```
src             dest          distance
-----------------------------------------
Newyork         Texas         680
Texas           Newyork       680
Newyork         Florida       210
Florida         Newyork       210
Florida         California    490
```

I want to select the distinct across src and dest if both are same i.e distance between Newyork and Texas is same as Texas and Newyork, so i want to display it as 1 entry instead of 2 entries in final output as shown below.

```
src             dest          distance
-----------------------------------------
Newyork         Texas         680
Newyork         Florida       210
Florida         California    490
```

Can someone please help us in getting query for same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `LEAST/GREATEST`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(src, dest) AS src, GREATEST(src,dest) AS dest, distance
FROM tab;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6ef69d3b2250da7b2cf8d793d59406e4)**

Comment: This does not maintain the original values of `src` and `dest` in the result set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're right(where there is single pair  then it could swap values). If order is critical then your solution will handle it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one method:

```
select t.src, t.dest, t.distance
from t
where t.src < t.dest
union all
select t.src, t.dest, t.distance
where t.src > t.dest and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.src = t.dest and t2.dest = t.src and
                        t2.distance = t.distance
                 );
```

This will preserve pairs where the distances are different.  However, it will only return a single row where the two distances are the same.  In addition, it will maintain the original ordering of `src`/`dest` in all rows.

This version can take advantage of an index on `(src, dest)` or `(src, dest, distance)`.  With such an index, it is probably the fastest way to do what you want.

Another method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by least(src, dest), greatest(src, dest), distance
                                order by distance  -- anything can go here
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of columns is important you can use a single NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT -- DISTINCT -- might be needed depending on possible duplicate
   src,dest,distance
FROM tab t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM tab t2
  WHERE t1.src = t2.dest
    AND t1.dest = t2.src
    AND t1.src > t2.src
    AND t1.distance = t2.distance
);
```